# SVG handwriting stroke clip-path is cut off on Safari

Tags: css, animation, svg, stroke

I have this SVG handwriting logo animated by increasing the stroke-dashoffset.

Chrome browser is fine. But on Safari, the animation is going so wrong, the letters is covered on Safari. Is there some iOS specific bug stroke-dashoffset or something that I'm not aware of?
[codepen](https://codepen.io/ReiraWorld/pen/YzpXWYy)

```css
svg{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
.squiggle {
  stroke-dasharray: 1589;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1589;
  animation: draw 2s linear both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="413" height="112"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 413 112" >
   <clipPath id="clippy">
<path d="M84.4688 20.8672C85.1719 20.8672 85.7812 21.125 86.2969 21.6406C86.8594 22.1094 87.1406 22.7422 87.1406 23.5391C87.1406 24.5703 86.6953 25.3438 85.8047 25.8594C85.6641 25.9531 85.0312 26.3984 83.9062 27.1953C82.8281 27.9922 81.6328 29.2812 80.3203 31.0625C79.0078 32.8438 77.7422 35.2109 76.5234 38.1641C75.3047 41.0703 74.5312 44.6797 74.2031 48.9922C74.1094 49.7422 74.0391 50.4922 73.9922 51.2422C73.9922 51.9922 73.9688 52.7422 73.9219 53.4922C74.7656 53.3984 75.6328 53.3281 76.5234 53.2812C77.4609 53.1875 78.4453 53.1406 79.4766 53.1406C82.8516 53.1406 86.1094 53.5156 89.25 54.2656C92.3906 55.0156 95.2734 56.0938 97.8984 57.5C104.695 54.7812 109.898 51.1719 113.508 46.6719C117.117 42.1719 118.922 37.1562 118.922 31.625C118.922 27.5 117.891 23.8438 115.828 20.6562C113.766 17.4219 110.859 14.7031 107.109 12.5C103.406 10.2969 98.9531 8.60938 93.75 7.4375C88.5938 6.26562 82.9219 5.67969 76.7344 5.67969C71.3438 5.67969 65.8359 6.10156 60.2109 6.94531C54.6328 7.74219 49.2188 8.96094 43.9688 10.6016C38.7656 12.2422 33.8672 14.2812 29.2734 16.7188C24.6797 19.1562 20.6719 21.9688 17.25 25.1562C13.8281 28.2969 11.1328 31.8125 9.16406 35.7031C7.19531 39.5938 6.21094 43.8125 6.21094 48.3594C6.21094 51.7344 6.79688 54.7109 7.96875 57.2891C9.14062 59.8203 10.6875 61.9531 12.6094 63.6875C14.5781 65.375 16.8281 66.6641 19.3594 67.5547C21.8906 68.3984 24.5391 68.8203 27.3047 68.8203C30.5859 68.8203 33.4688 68.4922 35.9531 67.8359C38.4375 67.1797 40.5234 66.4766 42.2109 65.7266C43.8984 64.9297 45.1641 64.2031 46.0078 63.5469C46.8984 62.8438 47.3906 62.4453 47.4844 62.3516C47.8125 62.1172 48.1875 61.8594 48.6094 61.5781C49.0312 61.25 49.4766 61.0859 49.9453 61.0859C50.6484 61.0859 51.2578 61.3438 51.7734 61.8594C52.2891 62.3281 52.5469 62.9375 52.5469 63.6875C52.5469 64.4375 52.2891 65.0469 51.7734 65.5156C51.6797 65.6094 51.0703 66.125 49.9453 67.0625C48.8672 67.9531 47.2969 68.9141 45.2344 69.9453C43.1719 70.9766 40.6406 71.9141 37.6406 72.7578C34.6875 73.6016 31.2891 74.0234 27.4453 74.0234C23.8828 74.0234 20.4844 73.4375 17.25 72.2656C14.0625 71.0938 11.25 69.4062 8.8125 67.2031C6.375 65 4.42969 62.3281 2.97656 59.1875C1.57031 56 0.867188 52.3906 0.867188 48.3594C0.867188 43.9062 1.78125 39.6406 3.60938 35.5625C5.4375 31.4375 8.01562 27.5938 11.3438 24.0312C14.6719 20.4688 18.6562 17.2578 23.2969 14.3984C27.9375 11.4922 33.0469 9.00781 38.625 6.94531C44.25 4.88281 50.2734 3.28906 56.6953 2.16406C63.1172 1.03906 69.75 0.476562 76.5938 0.476562C83.5781 0.476562 89.9766 1.17969 95.7891 2.58594C101.648 3.94531 106.688 5.9375 110.906 8.5625C115.125 11.1406 118.406 14.3281 120.75 18.125C123.094 21.875 124.266 26.1406 124.266 30.9219C124.266 37.25 122.438 42.9922 118.781 48.1484C115.172 53.3047 109.852 57.5938 102.82 61.0156C105.398 63.2188 107.414 65.7969 108.867 68.75C110.367 71.6562 111.469 74.6094 112.172 77.6094C112.922 80.6094 113.391 83.4688 113.578 86.1875C113.812 88.9062 113.977 91.1797 114.07 93.0078C114.164 95.6797 114.398 97.8594 114.773 99.5469C115.195 101.188 115.758 102.477 116.461 103.414C117.211 104.352 118.102 105.008 119.133 105.383C120.211 105.711 121.5 105.875 123 105.875C125.109 105.875 127.055 105.383 128.836 104.398C130.617 103.367 132.211 102.102 133.617 100.602C135.07 99.1016 136.336 97.4844 137.414 95.75C138.539 93.9688 139.477 92.3281 140.227 90.8281C140.977 89.2812 141.539 88.0156 141.914 87.0312C142.336 86 142.547 85.4609 142.547 85.4141C143.016 84.2422 143.836 83.6562 145.008 83.6562C145.805 83.6562 146.438 83.9375 146.906 84.5C147.422 85.0156 147.68 85.625 147.68 86.3281C147.68 86.5625 147.633 86.8672 147.539 87.2422C147.492 87.4297 147.211 88.1562 146.695 89.4219C146.227 90.6406 145.523 92.1406 144.586 93.9219C143.648 95.6562 142.477 97.5312 141.07 99.5469C139.664 101.562 138.023 103.438 136.148 105.172C134.32 106.859 132.234 108.266 129.891 109.391C127.594 110.516 125.039 111.078 122.227 111.078C119.742 111.078 117.656 110.68 115.969 109.883C114.328 109.086 112.969 107.938 111.891 106.438C110.859 104.891 110.086 103.039 109.57 100.883C109.102 98.6797 108.82 96.1719 108.727 93.3594C108.68 92.1875 108.609 90.8047 108.516 89.2109C108.422 87.5703 108.234 85.8594 107.953 84.0781C107.719 82.25 107.367 80.375 106.898 78.4531C106.43 76.5312 105.773 74.6562 104.93 72.8281C104.086 71 103.031 69.2656 101.766 67.625C100.5 65.9844 98.9531 64.5547 97.125 63.3359C93.5156 64.5547 89.7656 65.5156 85.875 66.2188C82.0312 66.875 78.0469 67.2266 73.9219 67.2734V69.3828C73.9219 75.1484 73.3359 80.5625 72.1641 85.625C71.0391 90.6406 69.1875 95.0234 66.6094 98.7734C64.0312 102.477 60.7031 105.383 56.625 107.492C52.5469 109.648 47.5781 110.727 41.7188 110.727C38.8125 110.727 35.9297 110.328 33.0703 109.531C30.2578 108.781 27.6094 107.727 25.125 106.367C22.6875 105.008 20.4844 103.414 18.5156 101.586C16.5938 99.7109 15.0703 97.6953 13.9453 95.5391C13.7109 95.1641 13.5938 94.7422 13.5938 94.2734C13.5938 93.6172 13.8281 93.0312 14.2969 92.5156C14.8125 91.9531 15.4688 91.6719 16.2656 91.6719C17.2969 91.6719 18.0703 92.1172 18.5859 93.0078C19.6172 94.8359 20.9531 96.5234 22.5938 98.0703C24.2344 99.6172 26.0625 100.953 28.0781 102.078C30.1406 103.156 32.3203 104 34.6172 104.609C36.9609 105.219 39.3281 105.523 41.7188 105.523C46.5469 105.523 50.6719 104.68 54.0938 102.992C57.5156 101.258 60.3047 98.8203 62.4609 95.6797C64.6172 92.4922 66.1875 88.6953 67.1719 84.2891C68.1562 79.8359 68.6484 74.8672 68.6484 69.3828V66.6406C67.1016 66.125 65.8594 65.3984 64.9219 64.4609C63.9844 63.5234 63.5156 62.375 63.5156 61.0156C63.5156 59.6562 63.9609 58.4609 64.8516 57.4297C65.7422 56.3984 67.0078 55.5547 68.6484 54.8984C68.6484 53.8203 68.6719 52.7656 68.7188 51.7344C68.7656 50.6562 68.8359 49.6016 68.9297 48.5703C69.2109 45.1953 69.7266 42.1719 70.4766 39.5C71.2734 36.8281 72.1875 34.4844 73.2188 32.4688C74.2969 30.4531 75.3984 28.7422 76.5234 27.3359C77.6484 25.9297 78.7031 24.7812 79.6875 23.8906C80.6719 22.9531 81.4922 22.2734 82.1484 21.8516C82.8047 21.4297 83.1797 21.1953 83.2734 21.1484C83.6016 20.9609 84 20.8672 84.4688 20.8672ZM91.0781 60.1016C90.2812 59.8672 89.5078 59.6328 88.7578 59.3984C88.0078 59.1641 87.1875 58.9766 86.2969 58.8359C85.4531 58.6484 84.4922 58.5078 83.4141 58.4141C82.3828 58.2734 81.1875 58.2031 79.8281 58.2031C77.3906 58.2031 75.3984 58.3438 73.8516 58.625V62.0703C76.7109 62.0703 79.6406 61.9062 82.6406 61.5781C85.6875 61.25 88.5 60.7578 91.0781 60.1016Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
<path d="M150.773 99.2656C151.758 100.625 153.023 101.727 154.57 102.57C156.117 103.367 158.016 103.766 160.266 103.766C162.562 103.766 164.648 103.227 166.523 102.148C168.398 101.023 170.109 99.5703 171.656 97.7891C173.203 96.0078 174.586 94.0156 175.805 91.8125C177.023 89.6094 178.125 87.4062 179.109 85.2031C179.344 84.6875 179.672 84.3125 180.094 84.0781C180.516 83.7969 180.984 83.6562 181.5 83.6562C182.297 83.6562 182.93 83.9375 183.398 84.5C183.914 85.0625 184.172 85.6719 184.172 86.3281C184.172 86.5625 184.148 86.7734 184.102 86.9609C184.055 87.1016 183.984 87.2656 183.891 87.4531C180.656 94.5781 177.117 99.9453 173.273 103.555C169.477 107.164 165.164 109.016 160.336 109.109C157.242 109.109 154.57 108.5 152.32 107.281C150.07 106.109 148.219 104.586 146.766 102.711C145.312 100.789 144.234 98.6328 143.531 96.2422C142.828 93.8516 142.477 91.4609 142.477 89.0703C142.477 86.6797 142.758 84.4766 143.32 82.4609C143.93 80.4453 144.773 78.6875 145.852 77.1875C146.977 75.6875 148.289 74.5156 149.789 73.6719C151.336 72.8281 153.023 72.4062 154.852 72.4062C155.93 72.4062 156.984 72.6406 158.016 73.1094C159.094 73.5312 160.055 74.1641 160.898 75.0078C161.742 75.8047 162.422 76.7891 162.938 77.9609C163.453 79.1328 163.711 80.4688 163.711 81.9688C163.711 83.8906 163.383 85.6953 162.727 87.3828C162.07 89.0703 161.156 90.6406 159.984 92.0938C158.859 93.5469 157.5 94.8828 155.906 96.1016C154.312 97.3203 152.602 98.375 150.773 99.2656ZM148.664 94.6953C150.117 94.0859 151.43 93.3125 152.602 92.375C153.82 91.4375 154.852 90.4062 155.695 89.2812C156.539 88.1562 157.195 86.9844 157.664 85.7656C158.133 84.5 158.367 83.2344 158.367 81.9688C158.367 80.5625 158.016 79.5078 157.312 78.8047C156.609 78.0547 155.789 77.6797 154.852 77.6797C153.586 77.6797 152.508 78.0312 151.617 78.7344C150.727 79.4375 150 80.3516 149.438 81.4766C148.875 82.6016 148.453 83.8672 148.172 85.2734C147.938 86.6328 147.82 87.9922 147.82 89.3516C147.82 90.1953 147.891 91.0859 148.031 92.0234C148.219 92.9609 148.43 93.8516 148.664 94.6953Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
<path d="M184.734 101.023C185.484 99.4297 186.352 97.7188 187.336 95.8906C188.32 94.0156 189.375 92.1172 190.5 90.1953C191.625 88.2266 192.82 86.2812 194.086 84.3594C195.352 82.4375 196.664 80.6328 198.023 78.9453C199.383 77.3047 200.742 76.1328 202.102 75.4297C203.508 74.6797 204.82 74.3047 206.039 74.3047C207.258 74.3047 208.312 74.5625 209.203 75.0781C210.141 75.5469 210.891 76.2031 211.453 77.0469C212.062 77.8906 212.508 78.875 212.789 80C213.117 81.125 213.281 82.3438 213.281 83.6562C213.281 84.7344 213.164 86.1875 212.93 88.0156C212.742 89.7969 212.648 91.6719 212.648 93.6406C212.648 94.7656 212.695 95.8906 212.789 97.0156C212.93 98.0938 213.141 99.0781 213.422 99.9688C213.75 100.812 214.219 101.516 214.828 102.078C215.438 102.594 216.234 102.852 217.219 102.852C218.344 102.852 219.469 102.547 220.594 101.938C221.719 101.281 222.82 100.438 223.898 99.4062C224.977 98.3281 226.008 97.1562 226.992 95.8906C227.977 94.5781 228.867 93.2891 229.664 92.0234C230.461 90.7109 231.164 89.4688 231.773 88.2969C232.383 87.0781 232.875 86.0703 233.25 85.2734C233.719 84.1953 234.539 83.6562 235.711 83.6562C236.508 83.6562 237.141 83.9375 237.609 84.5C238.078 85.0625 238.312 85.6719 238.312 86.3281C238.312 86.7031 238.242 87.0547 238.102 87.3828C237.914 87.7578 237.539 88.5312 236.977 89.7031C236.461 90.875 235.734 92.2344 234.797 93.7812C233.906 95.3281 232.852 96.9453 231.633 98.6328C230.414 100.32 229.055 101.891 227.555 103.344C226.102 104.75 224.508 105.922 222.773 106.859C221.086 107.75 219.305 108.195 217.43 108.195C215.273 108.195 213.539 107.75 212.227 106.859C210.914 105.922 209.883 104.75 209.133 103.344C208.43 101.938 207.938 100.367 207.656 98.6328C207.422 96.8984 207.305 95.2109 207.305 93.5703C207.305 92.7266 207.328 91.8359 207.375 90.8984C207.469 89.9141 207.562 88.9531 207.656 88.0156C207.75 87.0781 207.82 86.2109 207.867 85.4141C207.961 84.5703 208.008 83.8672 208.008 83.3047C208.008 81.8516 207.797 80.8672 207.375 80.3516C207 79.8359 206.555 79.5781 206.039 79.5781C205.289 79.5781 204.422 80.0234 203.438 80.9141C202.5 81.7578 201.492 82.8828 200.414 84.2891C199.383 85.6953 198.328 87.2891 197.25 89.0703C196.219 90.8047 195.211 92.5391 194.227 94.2734C193.242 96.0078 192.352 97.6719 191.555 99.2656C190.758 100.812 190.102 102.102 189.586 103.133C188.602 105.102 187.594 106.414 186.562 107.07C185.578 107.773 184.688 108.125 183.891 108.125C182.438 108.125 181.312 107.562 180.516 106.438C179.766 105.266 179.391 103.859 179.391 102.219V97.7891C179.391 88.9297 179.391 80.4922 179.391 72.4766C179.438 64.4141 179.555 56.9375 179.742 50.0469C179.977 43.1094 180.328 36.8516 180.797 31.2734C181.312 25.6484 182.062 20.8672 183.047 16.9297C184.031 12.9453 185.273 9.875 186.773 7.71875C188.32 5.5625 190.242 4.48438 192.539 4.48438C194.508 4.48438 196.172 5.02344 197.531 6.10156C198.891 7.17969 199.992 8.65625 200.836 10.5312C201.68 12.3594 202.289 14.5156 202.664 17C203.039 19.4375 203.227 22.0156 203.227 24.7344C203.227 30.2656 202.711 35.7031 201.68 41.0469C200.695 46.3438 199.359 51.5234 197.672 56.5859C195.984 61.6484 194.016 66.5938 191.766 71.4219C189.516 76.2031 187.148 80.8672 184.664 85.4141C184.664 86.2578 184.664 87.2656 184.664 88.4375C184.664 89.6094 184.664 90.7812 184.664 91.9531C184.664 93.125 184.664 94.2266 184.664 95.2578C184.664 96.2891 184.664 97.1094 184.664 97.7188L184.734 101.023ZM184.734 75.0781C186.703 70.7656 188.484 66.5703 190.078 62.4922C191.719 58.3672 193.102 54.2656 194.227 50.1875C195.398 46.1094 196.312 41.9844 196.969 37.8125C197.625 33.5938 197.953 29.2109 197.953 24.6641C197.953 23.9141 197.906 22.7188 197.812 21.0781C197.766 19.4375 197.555 17.7734 197.18 16.0859C196.852 14.3984 196.312 12.9219 195.562 11.6562C194.859 10.3906 193.852 9.75781 192.539 9.75781C191.508 9.75781 190.617 10.4609 189.867 11.8672C189.117 13.2266 188.461 15.1016 187.898 17.4922C187.336 19.8359 186.867 22.5781 186.492 25.7188C186.117 28.8594 185.812 32.1875 185.578 35.7031C185.344 39.2188 185.156 42.8281 185.016 46.5312C184.922 50.2344 184.852 53.8438 184.805 57.3594C184.758 60.8281 184.734 64.0859 184.734 67.1328C184.734 70.1797 184.734 72.8281 184.734 75.0781Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
<path d="M265.734 99.2656C264.562 99.2656 263.531 99.1719 262.641 98.9844C261.938 100.391 261.094 101.703 260.109 102.922C259.125 104.094 257.977 105.125 256.664 106.016C255.398 106.906 253.969 107.609 252.375 108.125C250.781 108.641 249.047 108.898 247.172 108.898C244.969 108.898 242.953 108.5 241.125 107.703C239.297 106.953 237.703 105.898 236.344 104.539C234.984 103.133 233.93 101.469 233.18 99.5469C232.43 97.5781 232.055 95.4219 232.055 93.0781C232.055 90.0781 232.594 87.4766 233.672 85.2734C234.75 83.0234 235.992 81.1719 237.398 79.7188C238.805 78.2188 240.211 77.1172 241.617 76.4141C243.023 75.6641 244.078 75.2891 244.781 75.2891C245.578 75.2891 246.164 75.5 246.539 75.9219C246.961 76.3438 247.172 76.9062 247.172 77.6094C247.172 78.4062 246.914 79.0156 246.398 79.4375C245.93 79.8125 245.32 80.1875 244.57 80.5625C243.82 80.9375 243.023 81.4766 242.18 82.1797C241.336 82.8359 240.539 83.6797 239.789 84.7109C239.086 85.7422 238.5 86.9609 238.031 88.3672C237.562 89.7734 237.328 91.3438 237.328 93.0781C237.328 94.625 237.562 96.0781 238.031 97.4375C238.5 98.75 239.18 99.8984 240.07 100.883C240.961 101.82 242.016 102.57 243.234 103.133C244.453 103.648 245.812 103.906 247.312 103.906C249.984 103.906 252.188 103.297 253.922 102.078C255.703 100.812 257.062 99.2188 258 97.2969C255.234 95.8438 252.961 93.7812 251.18 91.1094C249.398 88.4375 248.508 85.4375 248.508 82.1094C248.508 79.4375 249.141 77.2578 250.406 75.5703C251.719 73.8828 253.43 73.0391 255.539 73.0391C256.805 73.0391 258 73.3438 259.125 73.9531C260.25 74.5625 261.234 75.5234 262.078 76.8359C262.969 78.1484 263.672 79.8359 264.188 81.8984C264.703 83.9609 264.961 86.4219 264.961 89.2812C264.961 90.7812 264.773 92.3516 264.398 93.9922C264.68 94.0391 264.961 94.0625 265.242 94.0625C265.523 94.0625 265.828 94.0625 266.156 94.0625C267.75 94.0625 269.18 93.875 270.445 93.5C271.711 93.125 272.859 92.5625 273.891 91.8125C274.922 91.0625 275.836 90.1016 276.633 88.9297C277.477 87.7578 278.273 86.3984 279.023 84.8516C279.164 84.5703 279.469 84.3125 279.938 84.0781C280.406 83.7969 280.875 83.6562 281.344 83.6562C281.953 83.6562 282.516 83.9141 283.031 84.4297C283.594 84.8984 283.875 85.5312 283.875 86.3281C283.875 86.7031 283.781 87.125 283.594 87.5938C283.406 88.0156 283.219 88.4141 283.031 88.7891C282.234 90.1953 281.297 91.5547 280.219 92.8672C279.188 94.1328 277.945 95.2578 276.492 96.2422C275.086 97.1797 273.492 97.9297 271.711 98.4922C269.93 99.0547 267.938 99.3125 265.734 99.2656ZM253.711 81.5469C253.711 82.4375 253.828 83.375 254.062 84.3594C254.297 85.3438 254.648 86.3281 255.117 87.3125C255.633 88.25 256.242 89.1641 256.945 90.0547C257.695 90.8984 258.562 91.625 259.547 92.2344C259.688 91.25 259.758 90.2891 259.758 89.3516C259.758 88.0859 259.664 86.7969 259.477 85.4844C259.289 84.1719 259.008 82.9766 258.633 81.8984C258.305 80.7734 257.883 79.8828 257.367 79.2266C256.852 78.5234 256.242 78.1719 255.539 78.1719C255.258 78.1719 254.883 78.3828 254.414 78.8047C253.945 79.2266 253.711 80.1406 253.711 81.5469Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
<path d="M295.125 100.742C295.828 99.3359 296.719 97.6016 297.797 95.5391C298.922 93.4297 300.07 91.3203 301.242 89.2109C302.461 87.1016 303.633 85.1094 304.758 83.2344C305.93 81.3594 306.914 79.9297 307.711 78.9453C309.07 77.3047 310.477 76.1328 311.93 75.4297C313.383 74.7266 314.719 74.375 315.938 74.375C317.156 74.375 318.188 74.6328 319.031 75.1484C319.922 75.6641 320.648 76.3672 321.211 77.2578C321.773 78.1016 322.195 79.1094 322.477 80.2812C322.758 81.4062 322.898 82.625 322.898 83.9375C322.898 84.6875 322.852 85.6719 322.758 86.8906C322.711 88.1094 322.641 89.4219 322.547 90.8281C322.5 92.2344 322.43 93.6875 322.336 95.1875C322.289 96.6875 322.242 98.0938 322.195 99.4062C322.898 98 323.695 96.4531 324.586 94.7656C325.477 93.0312 326.367 91.3203 327.258 89.6328C328.195 87.9453 329.086 86.375 329.93 84.9219C330.773 83.4219 331.547 82.2031 332.25 81.2656C334.266 78.5 336.141 76.6484 337.875 75.7109C339.656 74.7734 341.227 74.3047 342.586 74.3047C344.18 74.3047 345.492 74.6094 346.523 75.2188C347.555 75.7812 348.352 76.5312 348.914 77.4688C349.523 78.3594 349.945 79.3672 350.18 80.4922C350.414 81.6172 350.531 82.6953 350.531 83.7266C350.531 85.3203 350.414 86.9844 350.18 88.7188C349.945 90.4531 349.828 92.5156 349.828 94.9062C349.828 95.8906 349.875 96.875 349.969 97.8594C350.062 98.8438 350.25 99.7109 350.531 100.461C350.859 101.211 351.352 101.82 352.008 102.289C352.664 102.758 353.555 102.992 354.68 102.992C355.898 102.992 357.094 102.688 358.266 102.078C359.438 101.422 360.562 100.578 361.641 99.5469C362.719 98.5156 363.727 97.3438 364.664 96.0312C365.648 94.7188 366.539 93.4062 367.336 92.0938C368.133 90.7812 368.836 89.5391 369.445 88.3672C370.055 87.1484 370.547 86.1172 370.922 85.2734C371.156 84.7578 371.484 84.3594 371.906 84.0781C372.328 83.7969 372.797 83.6562 373.312 83.6562C374.109 83.6562 374.742 83.9609 375.211 84.5703C375.727 85.1328 375.984 85.7422 375.984 86.3984C375.984 86.7266 375.914 87.0547 375.773 87.3828C375.586 87.7578 375.211 88.5547 374.648 89.7734C374.086 90.9453 373.336 92.3047 372.398 93.8516C371.461 95.3516 370.359 96.9453 369.094 98.6328C367.875 100.32 366.516 101.891 365.016 103.344C363.516 104.75 361.898 105.922 360.164 106.859C358.43 107.75 356.602 108.195 354.68 108.195C352.617 108.195 350.93 107.82 349.617 107.07C348.352 106.367 347.32 105.406 346.523 104.188C345.773 102.969 345.258 101.562 344.977 99.9688C344.695 98.375 344.555 96.7109 344.555 94.9766C344.555 92.6797 344.672 90.5703 344.906 88.6484C345.141 86.6797 345.258 85.1562 345.258 84.0781C345.258 82.9062 345.141 82.0156 344.906 81.4062C344.719 80.7969 344.461 80.375 344.133 80.1406C343.852 79.8594 343.57 79.7188 343.289 79.7188C343.008 79.6719 342.797 79.6484 342.656 79.6484C341.531 79.6484 340.336 80.2812 339.07 81.5469C337.852 82.7656 336.586 84.4062 335.273 86.4688C333.961 88.5312 332.602 90.875 331.195 93.5C329.836 96.125 328.453 98.7969 327.047 101.516C326.25 103.016 325.57 104.258 325.008 105.242C324.492 106.227 323.977 107 323.461 107.562C322.992 108.125 322.523 108.523 322.055 108.758C321.586 108.992 321.07 109.109 320.508 109.109C319.289 109.109 318.352 108.688 317.695 107.844C317.086 107 316.781 105.898 316.781 104.539C316.781 103.836 316.805 102.898 316.852 101.727C316.898 100.555 316.945 99.2656 316.992 97.8594C317.039 96.4531 317.109 95 317.203 93.5C317.297 92 317.367 90.5703 317.414 89.2109C317.461 87.8047 317.508 86.5625 317.555 85.4844C317.602 84.4062 317.625 83.5859 317.625 83.0234C317.625 81.8047 317.414 80.9375 316.992 80.4219C316.57 79.8594 316.078 79.5781 315.516 79.5781C315 79.5781 314.414 79.7656 313.758 80.1406C313.148 80.5156 312.422 81.2422 311.578 82.3203C310.922 83.1641 310.078 84.4062 309.047 86.0469C308.062 87.6406 307.008 89.4219 305.883 91.3906C304.758 93.3594 303.633 95.375 302.508 97.4375C301.43 99.5 300.492 101.352 299.695 102.992C298.711 104.961 297.727 106.297 296.742 107C295.758 107.75 294.797 108.125 293.859 108.125C292.5 108.125 291.492 107.727 290.836 106.93C290.18 106.086 289.852 104.984 289.852 103.625C289.852 103.484 289.875 102.641 289.922 101.094C290.016 99.5469 290.109 97.6719 290.203 95.4688C290.297 93.2188 290.391 90.8281 290.484 88.2969C290.625 85.7656 290.742 83.3984 290.836 81.1953C290.883 80.0234 290.836 78.9453 290.695 77.9609C290.555 76.9766 290.367 76.3906 290.133 76.2031C289.758 76.2969 289.008 77.1641 287.883 78.8047C286.805 80.4453 285.422 83.3047 283.734 87.3828C283.5 87.8984 283.148 88.2969 282.68 88.5781C282.211 88.8594 281.719 89 281.203 89C280.406 89 279.773 88.7422 279.305 88.2266C278.836 87.6641 278.602 87.0312 278.602 86.3281C278.602 86 278.672 85.6484 278.812 85.2734C280.922 80.2578 282.938 76.5781 284.859 74.2344C286.781 71.8438 288.656 70.6484 290.484 70.6484C291.562 70.6484 292.453 70.9062 293.156 71.4219C293.906 71.8906 294.492 72.5234 294.914 73.3203C295.336 74.0703 295.641 74.9375 295.828 75.9219C296.016 76.9062 296.109 77.8672 296.109 78.8047C296.109 82.9766 295.992 86.7969 295.758 90.2656C295.57 93.7344 295.359 97.2266 295.125 100.742Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
<path d="M379.43 99.2656C380.414 100.625 381.68 101.727 383.227 102.57C384.773 103.367 386.672 103.766 388.922 103.766C391.219 103.766 393.305 103.227 395.18 102.148C397.055 101.023 398.766 99.5703 400.312 97.7891C401.859 96.0078 403.242 94.0156 404.461 91.8125C405.68 89.6094 406.781 87.4062 407.766 85.2031C408 84.6875 408.328 84.3125 408.75 84.0781C409.172 83.7969 409.641 83.6562 410.156 83.6562C410.953 83.6562 411.586 83.9375 412.055 84.5C412.57 85.0625 412.828 85.6719 412.828 86.3281C412.828 86.5625 412.805 86.7734 412.758 86.9609C412.711 87.1016 412.641 87.2656 412.547 87.4531C409.312 94.5781 405.773 99.9453 401.93 103.555C398.133 107.164 393.82 109.016 388.992 109.109C385.898 109.109 383.227 108.5 380.977 107.281C378.727 106.109 376.875 104.586 375.422 102.711C373.969 100.789 372.891 98.6328 372.188 96.2422C371.484 93.8516 371.133 91.4609 371.133 89.0703C371.133 86.6797 371.414 84.4766 371.977 82.4609C372.586 80.4453 373.43 78.6875 374.508 77.1875C375.633 75.6875 376.945 74.5156 378.445 73.6719C379.992 72.8281 381.68 72.4062 383.508 72.4062C384.586 72.4062 385.641 72.6406 386.672 73.1094C387.75 73.5312 388.711 74.1641 389.555 75.0078C390.398 75.8047 391.078 76.7891 391.594 77.9609C392.109 79.1328 392.367 80.4688 392.367 81.9688C392.367 83.8906 392.039 85.6953 391.383 87.3828C390.727 89.0703 389.812 90.6406 388.641 92.0938C387.516 93.5469 386.156 94.8828 384.562 96.1016C382.969 97.3203 381.258 98.375 379.43 99.2656ZM377.32 94.6953C378.773 94.0859 380.086 93.3125 381.258 92.375C382.477 91.4375 383.508 90.4062 384.352 89.2812C385.195 88.1562 385.852 86.9844 386.32 85.7656C386.789 84.5 387.023 83.2344 387.023 81.9688C387.023 80.5625 386.672 79.5078 385.969 78.8047C385.266 78.0547 384.445 77.6797 383.508 77.6797C382.242 77.6797 381.164 78.0312 380.273 78.7344C379.383 79.4375 378.656 80.3516 378.094 81.4766C377.531 82.6016 377.109 83.8672 376.828 85.2734C376.594 86.6328 376.477 87.9922 376.477 89.3516C376.477 90.1953 376.547 91.0859 376.688 92.0234C376.875 92.9609 377.086 93.8516 377.32 94.6953Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
      </clipPath>
  
<path clip-path="url(#clippy)" class="squiggle" fill="none" stroke="#F8C5C5" stroke-miterlimit="100"   stroke-width="15"   stroke-linecap="round"
 d="M52.5 63.5L46 67.5H37.5L30 71.5H21.5L13.5 67.5L8 63.5L4 57.5L3 47.5L4 41.5L8 32.5L13.5 24.5L21.5 18.5L30 13L38.5 9L46 6.5L54.5 5.5L65.5 3H78H89.5L102.5 6.5L111.5 11L118.5 19.5L122.5 32.5L118.5 40.5L116.5 47.5L111.5 52.5L104.5 54.5L98.5 63.5H86H73.5H65.5V57.5L69.5 47.5L73.5 32.5L78 24.5L82.5 19.5L86 24.5L78 32.5L73.5 41.5V52.5L71.5 71.5L69.5 85.5L65.5 93.5L60 100.5L52.5 105L46 108.5H37.5L30 105L21.5 100.5L13.5 93.5V85.5L82.5 55.5L89.5 56.5L106.5 71.5L111.5 85.5V93.5V105L118.5 108.5H128.5L134 101.5L142 93.5L152 94.5L158.5 89L159.5 75.5H149.5L143.5 85.5L147.5 101.5L159.5 107L172.5 100.5L180 85.5L190 67.5L198.5 47.5V24.5V11L190 6.5L184 19.5L180 32.5V47.5V63.5V77.5V108.5L189 98.5L191 90L198.5 81L206 71.5L210 81L209 99.5L215.5 106L226.5 100.5L232.5 89L239.5 77.5H244L235.5 96.5L239.5 105H253.5L259.5 100.5L262.5 87.5V77.5V77.5C258.114 74.576 252.155 76.8797 250.877 81.9937L250 85.5L253.5 93.5L270 96.5L278 89L282.5 77.5L292 71.5V81V89V106.5L301.5 93.5L309.5 80L319.5 77.5V85.5V96.5V105L329.5 93.5L334.5 81L342.5 75.5L346.5 85.5L345.5 97.5L353.5 106L364 100.5L371.5 89L376.5 99.5L388.5 89V80L382.5 74.5L371.5 81.5L381.5 105L392.5 106L402 100.5L406 93.5L410.5 81"  
      />
 
</svg>
```

Comment: It looks fine on my iPad IOS 14 Safari apart from a tiny bit cut off on the top and bottom of the capital R. What do you see on Safari?

Comment: The same, it's the problem. Then I don't know how to fix it  on safari ?

Comment: Hi, @Kaiido has fixed it - the only problem is that your codepen works fine now so people may not see the bug in future.

Comment: Hi,@A Haworth Thanks you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more bug in Safari... you can let them know here: https://bugs.webkit.org/

It seems they do clip their clip-path to the svg's viewport, or something alike.

Using a `<mask>` works well though,

```css
.squiggle {
  stroke-dasharray: 1589;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1589;
  animation: draw 2s linear both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="413" height="112"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 413 112" >
   <mask id="masky">
<path d="M84.4688 20.8672C85.1719 20.8672 85.7812 21.125 86.2969 21.6406C86.8594 22.1094 87.1406 22.7422 87.1406 23.5391C87.1406 24.5703 86.6953 25.3438 85.8047 25.8594C85.6641 25.9531 85.0312 26.3984 83.9062 27.1953C82.8281 27.9922 81.6328 29.2812 80.3203 31.0625C79.0078 32.8438 77.7422 35.2109 76.5234 38.1641C75.3047 41.0703 74.5312 44.6797 74.2031 48.9922C74.1094 49.7422 74.0391 50.4922 73.9922 51.2422C73.9922 51.9922 73.9688 52.7422 73.9219 53.4922C74.7656 53.3984 75.6328 53.3281 76.5234 53.2812C77.4609 53.1875 78.4453 53.1406 79.4766 53.1406C82.8516 53.1406 86.1094 53.5156 89.25 54.2656C92.3906 55.0156 95.2734 56.0938 97.8984 57.5C104.695 54.7812 109.898 51.1719 113.508 46.6719C117.117 42.1719 118.922 37.1562 118.922 31.625C118.922 27.5 117.891 23.8438 115.828 20.6562C113.766 17.4219 110.859 14.7031 107.109 12.5C103.406 10.2969 98.9531 8.60938 93.75 7.4375C88.5938 6.26562 82.9219 5.67969 76.7344 5.67969C71.3438 5.67969 65.8359 6.10156 60.2109 6.94531C54.6328 7.74219 49.2188 8.96094 43.9688 10.6016C38.7656 12.2422 33.8672 14.2812 29.2734 16.7188C24.6797 19.1562 20.6719 21.9688 17.25 25.1562C13.8281 28.2969 11.1328 31.8125 9.16406 35.7031C7.19531 39.5938 6.21094 43.8125 6.21094 48.3594C6.21094 51.7344 6.79688 54.7109 7.96875 57.2891C9.14062 59.8203 10.6875 61.9531 12.6094 63.6875C14.5781 65.375 16.8281 66.6641 19.3594 67.5547C21.8906 68.3984 24.5391 68.8203 27.3047 68.8203C30.5859 68.8203 33.4688 68.4922 35.9531 67.8359C38.4375 67.1797 40.5234 66.4766 42.2109 65.7266C43.8984 64.9297 45.1641 64.2031 46.0078 63.5469C46.8984 62.8438 47.3906 62.4453 47.4844 62.3516C47.8125 62.1172 48.1875 61.8594 48.6094 61.5781C49.0312 61.25 49.4766 61.0859 49.9453 61.0859C50.6484 61.0859 51.2578 61.3438 51.7734 61.8594C52.2891 62.3281 52.5469 62.9375 52.5469 63.6875C52.5469 64.4375 52.2891 65.0469 51.7734 65.5156C51.6797 65.6094 51.0703 66.125 49.9453 67.0625C48.8672 67.9531 47.2969 68.9141 45.2344 69.9453C43.1719 70.9766 40.6406 71.9141 37.6406 72.7578C34.6875 73.6016 31.2891 74.0234 27.4453 74.0234C23.8828 74.0234 20.4844 73.4375 17.25 72.2656C14.0625 71.0938 11.25 69.4062 8.8125 67.2031C6.375 65 4.42969 62.3281 2.97656 59.1875C1.57031 56 0.867188 52.3906 0.867188 48.3594C0.867188 43.9062 1.78125 39.6406 3.60938 35.5625C5.4375 31.4375 8.01562 27.5938 11.3438 24.0312C14.6719 20.4688 18.6562 17.2578 23.2969 14.3984C27.9375 11.4922 33.0469 9.00781 38.625 6.94531C44.25 4.88281 50.2734 3.28906 56.6953 2.16406C63.1172 1.03906 69.75 0.476562 76.5938 0.476562C83.5781 0.476562 89.9766 1.17969 95.7891 2.58594C101.648 3.94531 106.688 5.9375 110.906 8.5625C115.125 11.1406 118.406 14.3281 120.75 18.125C123.094 21.875 124.266 26.1406 124.266 30.9219C124.266 37.25 122.438 42.9922 118.781 48.1484C115.172 53.3047 109.852 57.5938 102.82 61.0156C105.398 63.2188 107.414 65.7969 108.867 68.75C110.367 71.6562 111.469 74.6094 112.172 77.6094C112.922 80.6094 113.391 83.4688 113.578 86.1875C113.812 88.9062 113.977 91.1797 114.07 93.0078C114.164 95.6797 114.398 97.8594 114.773 99.5469C115.195 101.188 115.758 102.477 116.461 103.414C117.211 104.352 118.102 105.008 119.133 105.383C120.211 105.711 121.5 105.875 123 105.875C125.109 105.875 127.055 105.383 128.836 104.398C130.617 103.367 132.211 102.102 133.617 100.602C135.07 99.1016 136.336 97.4844 137.414 95.75C138.539 93.9688 139.477 92.3281 140.227 90.8281C140.977 89.2812 141.539 88.0156 141.914 87.0312C142.336 86 142.547 85.4609 142.547 85.4141C143.016 84.2422 143.836 83.6562 145.008 83.6562C145.805 83.6562 146.438 83.9375 146.906 84.5C147.422 85.0156 147.68 85.625 147.68 86.3281C147.68 86.5625 147.633 86.8672 147.539 87.2422C147.492 87.4297 147.211 88.1562 146.695 89.4219C146.227 90.6406 145.523 92.1406 144.586 93.9219C143.648 95.6562 142.477 97.5312 141.07 99.5469C139.664 101.562 138.023 103.438 136.148 105.172C134.32 106.859 132.234 108.266 129.891 109.391C127.594 110.516 125.039 111.078 122.227 111.078C119.742 111.078 117.656 110.68 115.969 109.883C114.328 109.086 112.969 107.938 111.891 106.438C110.859 104.891 110.086 103.039 109.57 100.883C109.102 98.6797 108.82 96.1719 108.727 93.3594C108.68 92.1875 108.609 90.8047 108.516 89.2109C108.422 87.5703 108.234 85.8594 107.953 84.0781C107.719 82.25 107.367 80.375 106.898 78.4531C106.43 76.5312 105.773 74.6562 104.93 72.8281C104.086 71 103.031 69.2656 101.766 67.625C100.5 65.9844 98.9531 64.5547 97.125 63.3359C93.5156 64.5547 89.7656 65.5156 85.875 66.2188C82.0312 66.875 78.0469 67.2266 73.9219 67.2734V69.3828C73.9219 75.1484 73.3359 80.5625 72.1641 85.625C71.0391 90.6406 69.1875 95.0234 66.6094 98.7734C64.0312 102.477 60.7031 105.383 56.625 107.492C52.5469 109.648 47.5781 110.727 41.7188 110.727C38.8125 110.727 35.9297 110.328 33.0703 109.531C30.2578 108.781 27.6094 107.727 25.125 106.367C22.6875 105.008 20.4844 103.414 18.5156 101.586C16.5938 99.7109 15.0703 97.6953 13.9453 95.5391C13.7109 95.1641 13.5938 94.7422 13.5938 94.2734C13.5938 93.6172 13.8281 93.0312 14.2969 92.5156C14.8125 91.9531 15.4688 91.6719 16.2656 91.6719C17.2969 91.6719 18.0703 92.1172 18.5859 93.0078C19.6172 94.8359 20.9531 96.5234 22.5938 98.0703C24.2344 99.6172 26.0625 100.953 28.0781 102.078C30.1406 103.156 32.3203 104 34.6172 104.609C36.9609 105.219 39.3281 105.523 41.7188 105.523C46.5469 105.523 50.6719 104.68 54.0938 102.992C57.5156 101.258 60.3047 98.8203 62.4609 95.6797C64.6172 92.4922 66.1875 88.6953 67.1719 84.2891C68.1562 79.8359 68.6484 74.8672 68.6484 69.3828V66.6406C67.1016 66.125 65.8594 65.3984 64.9219 64.4609C63.9844 63.5234 63.5156 62.375 63.5156 61.0156C63.5156 59.6562 63.9609 58.4609 64.8516 57.4297C65.7422 56.3984 67.0078 55.5547 68.6484 54.8984C68.6484 53.8203 68.6719 52.7656 68.7188 51.7344C68.7656 50.6562 68.8359 49.6016 68.9297 48.5703C69.2109 45.1953 69.7266 42.1719 70.4766 39.5C71.2734 36.8281 72.1875 34.4844 73.2188 32.4688C74.2969 30.4531 75.3984 28.7422 76.5234 27.3359C77.6484 25.9297 78.7031 24.7812 79.6875 23.8906C80.6719 22.9531 81.4922 22.2734 82.1484 21.8516C82.8047 21.4297 83.1797 21.1953 83.2734 21.1484C83.6016 20.9609 84 20.8672 84.4688 20.8672ZM91.0781 60.1016C90.2812 59.8672 89.5078 59.6328 88.7578 59.3984C88.0078 59.1641 87.1875 58.9766 86.2969 58.8359C85.4531 58.6484 84.4922 58.5078 83.4141 58.4141C82.3828 58.2734 81.1875 58.2031 79.8281 58.2031C77.3906 58.2031 75.3984 58.3438 73.8516 58.625V62.0703C76.7109 62.0703 79.6406 61.9062 82.6406 61.5781C85.6875 61.25 88.5 60.7578 91.0781 60.1016Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
<path d="M150.773 99.2656C151.758 100.625 153.023 101.727 154.57 102.57C156.117 103.367 158.016 103.766 160.266 103.766C162.562 103.766 164.648 103.227 166.523 102.148C168.398 101.023 170.109 99.5703 171.656 97.7891C173.203 96.0078 174.586 94.0156 175.805 91.8125C177.023 89.6094 178.125 87.4062 179.109 85.2031C179.344 84.6875 179.672 84.3125 180.094 84.0781C180.516 83.7969 180.984 83.6562 181.5 83.6562C182.297 83.6562 182.93 83.9375 183.398 84.5C183.914 85.0625 184.172 85.6719 184.172 86.3281C184.172 86.5625 184.148 86.7734 184.102 86.9609C184.055 87.1016 183.984 87.2656 183.891 87.4531C180.656 94.5781 177.117 99.9453 173.273 103.555C169.477 107.164 165.164 109.016 160.336 109.109C157.242 109.109 154.57 108.5 152.32 107.281C150.07 106.109 148.219 104.586 146.766 102.711C145.312 100.789 144.234 98.6328 143.531 96.2422C142.828 93.8516 142.477 91.4609 142.477 89.0703C142.477 86.6797 142.758 84.4766 143.32 82.4609C143.93 80.4453 144.773 78.6875 145.852 77.1875C146.977 75.6875 148.289 74.5156 149.789 73.6719C151.336 72.8281 153.023 72.4062 154.852 72.4062C155.93 72.4062 156.984 72.6406 158.016 73.1094C159.094 73.5312 160.055 74.1641 160.898 75.0078C161.742 75.8047 162.422 76.7891 162.938 77.9609C163.453 79.1328 163.711 80.4688 163.711 81.9688C163.711 83.8906 163.383 85.6953 162.727 87.3828C162.07 89.0703 161.156 90.6406 159.984 92.0938C158.859 93.5469 157.5 94.8828 155.906 96.1016C154.312 97.3203 152.602 98.375 150.773 99.2656ZM148.664 94.6953C150.117 94.0859 151.43 93.3125 152.602 92.375C153.82 91.4375 154.852 90.4062 155.695 89.2812C156.539 88.1562 157.195 86.9844 157.664 85.7656C158.133 84.5 158.367 83.2344 158.367 81.9688C158.367 80.5625 158.016 79.5078 157.312 78.8047C156.609 78.0547 155.789 77.6797 154.852 77.6797C153.586 77.6797 152.508 78.0312 151.617 78.7344C150.727 79.4375 150 80.3516 149.438 81.4766C148.875 82.6016 148.453 83.8672 148.172 85.2734C147.938 86.6328 147.82 87.9922 147.82 89.3516C147.82 90.1953 147.891 91.0859 148.031 92.0234C148.219 92.9609 148.43 93.8516 148.664 94.6953Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
<path d="M184.734 101.023C185.484 99.4297 186.352 97.7188 187.336 95.8906C188.32 94.0156 189.375 92.1172 190.5 90.1953C191.625 88.2266 192.82 86.2812 194.086 84.3594C195.352 82.4375 196.664 80.6328 198.023 78.9453C199.383 77.3047 200.742 76.1328 202.102 75.4297C203.508 74.6797 204.82 74.3047 206.039 74.3047C207.258 74.3047 208.312 74.5625 209.203 75.0781C210.141 75.5469 210.891 76.2031 211.453 77.0469C212.062 77.8906 212.508 78.875 212.789 80C213.117 81.125 213.281 82.3438 213.281 83.6562C213.281 84.7344 213.164 86.1875 212.93 88.0156C212.742 89.7969 212.648 91.6719 212.648 93.6406C212.648 94.7656 212.695 95.8906 212.789 97.0156C212.93 98.0938 213.141 99.0781 213.422 99.9688C213.75 100.812 214.219 101.516 214.828 102.078C215.438 102.594 216.234 102.852 217.219 102.852C218.344 102.852 219.469 102.547 220.594 101.938C221.719 101.281 222.82 100.438 223.898 99.4062C224.977 98.3281 226.008 97.1562 226.992 95.8906C227.977 94.5781 228.867 93.2891 229.664 92.0234C230.461 90.7109 231.164 89.4688 231.773 88.2969C232.383 87.0781 232.875 86.0703 233.25 85.2734C233.719 84.1953 234.539 83.6562 235.711 83.6562C236.508 83.6562 237.141 83.9375 237.609 84.5C238.078 85.0625 238.312 85.6719 238.312 86.3281C238.312 86.7031 238.242 87.0547 238.102 87.3828C237.914 87.7578 237.539 88.5312 236.977 89.7031C236.461 90.875 235.734 92.2344 234.797 93.7812C233.906 95.3281 232.852 96.9453 231.633 98.6328C230.414 100.32 229.055 101.891 227.555 103.344C226.102 104.75 224.508 105.922 222.773 106.859C221.086 107.75 219.305 108.195 217.43 108.195C215.273 108.195 213.539 107.75 212.227 106.859C210.914 105.922 209.883 104.75 209.133 103.344C208.43 101.938 207.938 100.367 207.656 98.6328C207.422 96.8984 207.305 95.2109 207.305 93.5703C207.305 92.7266 207.328 91.8359 207.375 90.8984C207.469 89.9141 207.562 88.9531 207.656 88.0156C207.75 87.0781 207.82 86.2109 207.867 85.4141C207.961 84.5703 208.008 83.8672 208.008 83.3047C208.008 81.8516 207.797 80.8672 207.375 80.3516C207 79.8359 206.555 79.5781 206.039 79.5781C205.289 79.5781 204.422 80.0234 203.438 80.9141C202.5 81.7578 201.492 82.8828 200.414 84.2891C199.383 85.6953 198.328 87.2891 197.25 89.0703C196.219 90.8047 195.211 92.5391 194.227 94.2734C193.242 96.0078 192.352 97.6719 191.555 99.2656C190.758 100.812 190.102 102.102 189.586 103.133C188.602 105.102 187.594 106.414 186.562 107.07C185.578 107.773 184.688 108.125 183.891 108.125C182.438 108.125 181.312 107.562 180.516 106.438C179.766 105.266 179.391 103.859 179.391 102.219V97.7891C179.391 88.9297 179.391 80.4922 179.391 72.4766C179.438 64.4141 179.555 56.9375 179.742 50.0469C179.977 43.1094 180.328 36.8516 180.797 31.2734C181.312 25.6484 182.062 20.8672 183.047 16.9297C184.031 12.9453 185.273 9.875 186.773 7.71875C188.32 5.5625 190.242 4.48438 192.539 4.48438C194.508 4.48438 196.172 5.02344 197.531 6.10156C198.891 7.17969 199.992 8.65625 200.836 10.5312C201.68 12.3594 202.289 14.5156 202.664 17C203.039 19.4375 203.227 22.0156 203.227 24.7344C203.227 30.2656 202.711 35.7031 201.68 41.0469C200.695 46.3438 199.359 51.5234 197.672 56.5859C195.984 61.6484 194.016 66.5938 191.766 71.4219C189.516 76.2031 187.148 80.8672 184.664 85.4141C184.664 86.2578 184.664 87.2656 184.664 88.4375C184.664 89.6094 184.664 90.7812 184.664 91.9531C184.664 93.125 184.664 94.2266 184.664 95.2578C184.664 96.2891 184.664 97.1094 184.664 97.7188L184.734 101.023ZM184.734 75.0781C186.703 70.7656 188.484 66.5703 190.078 62.4922C191.719 58.3672 193.102 54.2656 194.227 50.1875C195.398 46.1094 196.312 41.9844 196.969 37.8125C197.625 33.5938 197.953 29.2109 197.953 24.6641C197.953 23.9141 197.906 22.7188 197.812 21.0781C197.766 19.4375 197.555 17.7734 197.18 16.0859C196.852 14.3984 196.312 12.9219 195.562 11.6562C194.859 10.3906 193.852 9.75781 192.539 9.75781C191.508 9.75781 190.617 10.4609 189.867 11.8672C189.117 13.2266 188.461 15.1016 187.898 17.4922C187.336 19.8359 186.867 22.5781 186.492 25.7188C186.117 28.8594 185.812 32.1875 185.578 35.7031C185.344 39.2188 185.156 42.8281 185.016 46.5312C184.922 50.2344 184.852 53.8438 184.805 57.3594C184.758 60.8281 184.734 64.0859 184.734 67.1328C184.734 70.1797 184.734 72.8281 184.734 75.0781Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
<path d="M265.734 99.2656C264.562 99.2656 263.531 99.1719 262.641 98.9844C261.938 100.391 261.094 101.703 260.109 102.922C259.125 104.094 257.977 105.125 256.664 106.016C255.398 106.906 253.969 107.609 252.375 108.125C250.781 108.641 249.047 108.898 247.172 108.898C244.969 108.898 242.953 108.5 241.125 107.703C239.297 106.953 237.703 105.898 236.344 104.539C234.984 103.133 233.93 101.469 233.18 99.5469C232.43 97.5781 232.055 95.4219 232.055 93.0781C232.055 90.0781 232.594 87.4766 233.672 85.2734C234.75 83.0234 235.992 81.1719 237.398 79.7188C238.805 78.2188 240.211 77.1172 241.617 76.4141C243.023 75.6641 244.078 75.2891 244.781 75.2891C245.578 75.2891 246.164 75.5 246.539 75.9219C246.961 76.3438 247.172 76.9062 247.172 77.6094C247.172 78.4062 246.914 79.0156 246.398 79.4375C245.93 79.8125 245.32 80.1875 244.57 80.5625C243.82 80.9375 243.023 81.4766 242.18 82.1797C241.336 82.8359 240.539 83.6797 239.789 84.7109C239.086 85.7422 238.5 86.9609 238.031 88.3672C237.562 89.7734 237.328 91.3438 237.328 93.0781C237.328 94.625 237.562 96.0781 238.031 97.4375C238.5 98.75 239.18 99.8984 240.07 100.883C240.961 101.82 242.016 102.57 243.234 103.133C244.453 103.648 245.812 103.906 247.312 103.906C249.984 103.906 252.188 103.297 253.922 102.078C255.703 100.812 257.062 99.2188 258 97.2969C255.234 95.8438 252.961 93.7812 251.18 91.1094C249.398 88.4375 248.508 85.4375 248.508 82.1094C248.508 79.4375 249.141 77.2578 250.406 75.5703C251.719 73.8828 253.43 73.0391 255.539 73.0391C256.805 73.0391 258 73.3438 259.125 73.9531C260.25 74.5625 261.234 75.5234 262.078 76.8359C262.969 78.1484 263.672 79.8359 264.188 81.8984C264.703 83.9609 264.961 86.4219 264.961 89.2812C264.961 90.7812 264.773 92.3516 264.398 93.9922C264.68 94.0391 264.961 94.0625 265.242 94.0625C265.523 94.0625 265.828 94.0625 266.156 94.0625C267.75 94.0625 269.18 93.875 270.445 93.5C271.711 93.125 272.859 92.5625 273.891 91.8125C274.922 91.0625 275.836 90.1016 276.633 88.9297C277.477 87.7578 278.273 86.3984 279.023 84.8516C279.164 84.5703 279.469 84.3125 279.938 84.0781C280.406 83.7969 280.875 83.6562 281.344 83.6562C281.953 83.6562 282.516 83.9141 283.031 84.4297C283.594 84.8984 283.875 85.5312 283.875 86.3281C283.875 86.7031 283.781 87.125 283.594 87.5938C283.406 88.0156 283.219 88.4141 283.031 88.7891C282.234 90.1953 281.297 91.5547 280.219 92.8672C279.188 94.1328 277.945 95.2578 276.492 96.2422C275.086 97.1797 273.492 97.9297 271.711 98.4922C269.93 99.0547 267.938 99.3125 265.734 99.2656ZM253.711 81.5469C253.711 82.4375 253.828 83.375 254.062 84.3594C254.297 85.3438 254.648 86.3281 255.117 87.3125C255.633 88.25 256.242 89.1641 256.945 90.0547C257.695 90.8984 258.562 91.625 259.547 92.2344C259.688 91.25 259.758 90.2891 259.758 89.3516C259.758 88.0859 259.664 86.7969 259.477 85.4844C259.289 84.1719 259.008 82.9766 258.633 81.8984C258.305 80.7734 257.883 79.8828 257.367 79.2266C256.852 78.5234 256.242 78.1719 255.539 78.1719C255.258 78.1719 254.883 78.3828 254.414 78.8047C253.945 79.2266 253.711 80.1406 253.711 81.5469Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
<path d="M295.125 100.742C295.828 99.3359 296.719 97.6016 297.797 95.5391C298.922 93.4297 300.07 91.3203 301.242 89.2109C302.461 87.1016 303.633 85.1094 304.758 83.2344C305.93 81.3594 306.914 79.9297 307.711 78.9453C309.07 77.3047 310.477 76.1328 311.93 75.4297C313.383 74.7266 314.719 74.375 315.938 74.375C317.156 74.375 318.188 74.6328 319.031 75.1484C319.922 75.6641 320.648 76.3672 321.211 77.2578C321.773 78.1016 322.195 79.1094 322.477 80.2812C322.758 81.4062 322.898 82.625 322.898 83.9375C322.898 84.6875 322.852 85.6719 322.758 86.8906C322.711 88.1094 322.641 89.4219 322.547 90.8281C322.5 92.2344 322.43 93.6875 322.336 95.1875C322.289 96.6875 322.242 98.0938 322.195 99.4062C322.898 98 323.695 96.4531 324.586 94.7656C325.477 93.0312 326.367 91.3203 327.258 89.6328C328.195 87.9453 329.086 86.375 329.93 84.9219C330.773 83.4219 331.547 82.2031 332.25 81.2656C334.266 78.5 336.141 76.6484 337.875 75.7109C339.656 74.7734 341.227 74.3047 342.586 74.3047C344.18 74.3047 345.492 74.6094 346.523 75.2188C347.555 75.7812 348.352 76.5312 348.914 77.4688C349.523 78.3594 349.945 79.3672 350.18 80.4922C350.414 81.6172 350.531 82.6953 350.531 83.7266C350.531 85.3203 350.414 86.9844 350.18 88.7188C349.945 90.4531 349.828 92.5156 349.828 94.9062C349.828 95.8906 349.875 96.875 349.969 97.8594C350.062 98.8438 350.25 99.7109 350.531 100.461C350.859 101.211 351.352 101.82 352.008 102.289C352.664 102.758 353.555 102.992 354.68 102.992C355.898 102.992 357.094 102.688 358.266 102.078C359.438 101.422 360.562 100.578 361.641 99.5469C362.719 98.5156 363.727 97.3438 364.664 96.0312C365.648 94.7188 366.539 93.4062 367.336 92.0938C368.133 90.7812 368.836 89.5391 369.445 88.3672C370.055 87.1484 370.547 86.1172 370.922 85.2734C371.156 84.7578 371.484 84.3594 371.906 84.0781C372.328 83.7969 372.797 83.6562 373.312 83.6562C374.109 83.6562 374.742 83.9609 375.211 84.5703C375.727 85.1328 375.984 85.7422 375.984 86.3984C375.984 86.7266 375.914 87.0547 375.773 87.3828C375.586 87.7578 375.211 88.5547 374.648 89.7734C374.086 90.9453 373.336 92.3047 372.398 93.8516C371.461 95.3516 370.359 96.9453 369.094 98.6328C367.875 100.32 366.516 101.891 365.016 103.344C363.516 104.75 361.898 105.922 360.164 106.859C358.43 107.75 356.602 108.195 354.68 108.195C352.617 108.195 350.93 107.82 349.617 107.07C348.352 106.367 347.32 105.406 346.523 104.188C345.773 102.969 345.258 101.562 344.977 99.9688C344.695 98.375 344.555 96.7109 344.555 94.9766C344.555 92.6797 344.672 90.5703 344.906 88.6484C345.141 86.6797 345.258 85.1562 345.258 84.0781C345.258 82.9062 345.141 82.0156 344.906 81.4062C344.719 80.7969 344.461 80.375 344.133 80.1406C343.852 79.8594 343.57 79.7188 343.289 79.7188C343.008 79.6719 342.797 79.6484 342.656 79.6484C341.531 79.6484 340.336 80.2812 339.07 81.5469C337.852 82.7656 336.586 84.4062 335.273 86.4688C333.961 88.5312 332.602 90.875 331.195 93.5C329.836 96.125 328.453 98.7969 327.047 101.516C326.25 103.016 325.57 104.258 325.008 105.242C324.492 106.227 323.977 107 323.461 107.562C322.992 108.125 322.523 108.523 322.055 108.758C321.586 108.992 321.07 109.109 320.508 109.109C319.289 109.109 318.352 108.688 317.695 107.844C317.086 107 316.781 105.898 316.781 104.539C316.781 103.836 316.805 102.898 316.852 101.727C316.898 100.555 316.945 99.2656 316.992 97.8594C317.039 96.4531 317.109 95 317.203 93.5C317.297 92 317.367 90.5703 317.414 89.2109C317.461 87.8047 317.508 86.5625 317.555 85.4844C317.602 84.4062 317.625 83.5859 317.625 83.0234C317.625 81.8047 317.414 80.9375 316.992 80.4219C316.57 79.8594 316.078 79.5781 315.516 79.5781C315 79.5781 314.414 79.7656 313.758 80.1406C313.148 80.5156 312.422 81.2422 311.578 82.3203C310.922 83.1641 310.078 84.4062 309.047 86.0469C308.062 87.6406 307.008 89.4219 305.883 91.3906C304.758 93.3594 303.633 95.375 302.508 97.4375C301.43 99.5 300.492 101.352 299.695 102.992C298.711 104.961 297.727 106.297 296.742 107C295.758 107.75 294.797 108.125 293.859 108.125C292.5 108.125 291.492 107.727 290.836 106.93C290.18 106.086 289.852 104.984 289.852 103.625C289.852 103.484 289.875 102.641 289.922 101.094C290.016 99.5469 290.109 97.6719 290.203 95.4688C290.297 93.2188 290.391 90.8281 290.484 88.2969C290.625 85.7656 290.742 83.3984 290.836 81.1953C290.883 80.0234 290.836 78.9453 290.695 77.9609C290.555 76.9766 290.367 76.3906 290.133 76.2031C289.758 76.2969 289.008 77.1641 287.883 78.8047C286.805 80.4453 285.422 83.3047 283.734 87.3828C283.5 87.8984 283.148 88.2969 282.68 88.5781C282.211 88.8594 281.719 89 281.203 89C280.406 89 279.773 88.7422 279.305 88.2266C278.836 87.6641 278.602 87.0312 278.602 86.3281C278.602 86 278.672 85.6484 278.812 85.2734C280.922 80.2578 282.938 76.5781 284.859 74.2344C286.781 71.8438 288.656 70.6484 290.484 70.6484C291.562 70.6484 292.453 70.9062 293.156 71.4219C293.906 71.8906 294.492 72.5234 294.914 73.3203C295.336 74.0703 295.641 74.9375 295.828 75.9219C296.016 76.9062 296.109 77.8672 296.109 78.8047C296.109 82.9766 295.992 86.7969 295.758 90.2656C295.57 93.7344 295.359 97.2266 295.125 100.742Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
<path d="M379.43 99.2656C380.414 100.625 381.68 101.727 383.227 102.57C384.773 103.367 386.672 103.766 388.922 103.766C391.219 103.766 393.305 103.227 395.18 102.148C397.055 101.023 398.766 99.5703 400.312 97.7891C401.859 96.0078 403.242 94.0156 404.461 91.8125C405.68 89.6094 406.781 87.4062 407.766 85.2031C408 84.6875 408.328 84.3125 408.75 84.0781C409.172 83.7969 409.641 83.6562 410.156 83.6562C410.953 83.6562 411.586 83.9375 412.055 84.5C412.57 85.0625 412.828 85.6719 412.828 86.3281C412.828 86.5625 412.805 86.7734 412.758 86.9609C412.711 87.1016 412.641 87.2656 412.547 87.4531C409.312 94.5781 405.773 99.9453 401.93 103.555C398.133 107.164 393.82 109.016 388.992 109.109C385.898 109.109 383.227 108.5 380.977 107.281C378.727 106.109 376.875 104.586 375.422 102.711C373.969 100.789 372.891 98.6328 372.188 96.2422C371.484 93.8516 371.133 91.4609 371.133 89.0703C371.133 86.6797 371.414 84.4766 371.977 82.4609C372.586 80.4453 373.43 78.6875 374.508 77.1875C375.633 75.6875 376.945 74.5156 378.445 73.6719C379.992 72.8281 381.68 72.4062 383.508 72.4062C384.586 72.4062 385.641 72.6406 386.672 73.1094C387.75 73.5312 388.711 74.1641 389.555 75.0078C390.398 75.8047 391.078 76.7891 391.594 77.9609C392.109 79.1328 392.367 80.4688 392.367 81.9688C392.367 83.8906 392.039 85.6953 391.383 87.3828C390.727 89.0703 389.812 90.6406 388.641 92.0938C387.516 93.5469 386.156 94.8828 384.562 96.1016C382.969 97.3203 381.258 98.375 379.43 99.2656ZM377.32 94.6953C378.773 94.0859 380.086 93.3125 381.258 92.375C382.477 91.4375 383.508 90.4062 384.352 89.2812C385.195 88.1562 385.852 86.9844 386.32 85.7656C386.789 84.5 387.023 83.2344 387.023 81.9688C387.023 80.5625 386.672 79.5078 385.969 78.8047C385.266 78.0547 384.445 77.6797 383.508 77.6797C382.242 77.6797 381.164 78.0312 380.273 78.7344C379.383 79.4375 378.656 80.3516 378.094 81.4766C377.531 82.6016 377.109 83.8672 376.828 85.2734C376.594 86.6328 376.477 87.9922 376.477 89.3516C376.477 90.1953 376.547 91.0859 376.688 92.0234C376.875 92.9609 377.086 93.8516 377.32 94.6953Z" fill="#84A6FF"/>
  </mask>
  
<path mask="url(#masky)" class="squiggle" fill="none" stroke="#F8C5C5" stroke-miterlimit="100"   stroke-width="15"   stroke-linecap="round"
 d="M52.5 63.5L46 67.5H37.5L30 71.5H21.5L13.5 67.5L8 63.5L4 57.5L3 47.5L4 41.5L8 32.5L13.5 24.5L21.5 18.5L30 13L38.5 9L46 6.5L54.5 5.5L65.5 3H78H89.5L102.5 6.5L111.5 11L118.5 19.5L122.5 32.5L118.5 40.5L116.5 47.5L111.5 52.5L104.5 54.5L98.5 63.5H86H73.5H65.5V57.5L69.5 47.5L73.5 32.5L78 24.5L82.5 19.5L86 24.5L78 32.5L73.5 41.5V52.5L71.5 71.5L69.5 85.5L65.5 93.5L60 100.5L52.5 105L46 108.5H37.5L30 105L21.5 100.5L13.5 93.5V85.5L82.5 55.5L89.5 56.5L106.5 71.5L111.5 85.5V93.5V105L118.5 108.5H128.5L134 101.5L142 93.5L152 94.5L158.5 89L159.5 75.5H149.5L143.5 85.5L147.5 101.5L159.5 107L172.5 100.5L180 85.5L190 67.5L198.5 47.5V24.5V11L190 6.5L184 19.5L180 32.5V47.5V63.5V77.5V108.5L189 98.5L191 90L198.5 81L206 71.5L210 81L209 99.5L215.5 106L226.5 100.5L232.5 89L239.5 77.5H244L235.5 96.5L239.5 105H253.5L259.5 100.5L262.5 87.5V77.5V77.5C258.114 74.576 252.155 76.8797 250.877 81.9937L250 85.5L253.5 93.5L270 96.5L278 89L282.5 77.5L292 71.5V81V89V106.5L301.5 93.5L309.5 80L319.5 77.5V85.5V96.5V105L329.5 93.5L334.5 81L342.5 75.5L346.5 85.5L345.5 97.5L353.5 106L364 100.5L371.5 89L376.5 99.5L388.5 89V80L382.5 74.5L371.5 81.5L381.5 105L392.5 106L402 100.5L406 93.5L410.5 81"  
      />
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's work perfect for me.And let us know it's a bug about clip-path.